# How to go back in subversion?

Tags: svn

I found my recent work form revision 21 to current 25 is messy, but revision 20 is good. Thus I re-worked based on revision 20. But I cannot commit my new work if not updating to current revision 25. How can I remove revision 21-25 and commit my new work to the repository? It doesn't matter if the new committed revision number is 21 or 26. I am using Tortoise Subversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Update to latest version
2. Right click on top folder where you want to revert
3. TortoiseSVN -> SVN Show log
4. Right click on the revision you want to revert to (20 in this case)
5. Select "Revert to this revision"
6. Now your working copy will contain modified files as they looked in r20
7. Check in the modified files (With comment like "reverting to r20")
8. Continue working as usual.